# azure devops - gradle authentication

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, build.gradle, azure-artifacts

I am trying to configure build.gradle with azure devops artifacts repo.  It was working earlier with AZURE_ARTIFACTS credentials BUT azure recently changed the way build.gradle connects to artifacts repo

```
    url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dp-name/_packaging/dp-name/maven/v1'
    name 'dp-name'
        authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
   }
  }
```

gradle build fails with the following error

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > You cannot configure authentication schemes for this repository type if no credentials are provided.

* Try:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it once worked but recently fails, you may need to check if the **PAT** is still valid. Try creating a new **PAT** and use it in `settings.xml` file to check.

[image]

And please make sure you use the latest setup way to configure the authentication:

1.Add this section to your build.gradle file in both the repositories and publishing.repositories containers:

```
maven {
    url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_packaging/xxx/maven/v1'
    name 'xxx'
    authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
}
```

2.Add or edit the settings.xml file in ${user.home}/.m2:

```
<server>
  <id>looi</id>
  <username>xxx</username>
  <password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Did all this, but still getting the error. I'm able to publish but I can't download from another app

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT where is the settings.xml file located. I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Do you leave the brackets around the personal access token?

Comment: @Keverly No replace the brackets

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue with a multi-project build that I was able to solve with a hint on this documentation page on subprojects and plugins: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl

This is what my root build.gradle file looks like - Note: I did not have to edit the subprojects build.gradle files.

```
plugins {
    id "net.linguica.maven-settings" version "0.5"
}

...

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<repoId>/_packaging/platform/maven/v1'
        name '<name>'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

...

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'net.linguica.maven-settings'

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding maven settings plugin:

```
buildscript {
...
  dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "net.linguica.gradle:maven-settings-plugin:0.5"
  }
}
apply plugin: 'net.linguica.maven-settings'
```

After that gradle succeed with authorization to azure feed.

Comment: This was my issue too. The credentials were set up in `.m2/settings.xml` but without the above plugin, there's no way gradle can access the credentials.

An alternative if using the plugins block:
`plugins{
  id 'net.linguica.maven-settings' version "0.5"
}
`

Answer (score 6):

To get this right for plugins etc. this worked for me:

In `azure-pipelines` add token environment variable:

```
  - task: Gradle@2
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

In `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle` configure the appropriate repositories as follows:

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<your project>/amplify/_packaging/<your feed>/maven/v1'
            name = '<your feed>'
            credentials {
                username "AzureDevOps"
                password "$System.env.SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
```

Some references:

[How to log into Azure DevOps Artifact feed without token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885839/how-to-log-into-azure-devops-artifact-feed-without-token)

https://medium.com/developer-space/using-external-and-authentication-required-maven-repository-with-gradle-7e2e7c5b795d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken

Comment: In my build.gradle.kts file I had to use a slightly different syntax `password = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As well as adding the required section to `build.gradle`, you also need to add a Personal Access Token to `~/.m2/settings.xml`

If you don't already have  `~/.m2` directory or `settings.xml` file within it these can be created.

There's documentation on this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops

Or from the 'Connect to Feed' button within your Azure Devops > Artifacts page.