# How to log into Azure DevOps Artifact feed without token

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have a Azure DevOps artifact feed that we set up. In the same project as the artifact I have created a gradle build and using a token as the password I can access the artifact feed to have it access artifacts. Someone in my department thinks that there might be a way to access the artifact repo without a token. I tried using System.AccessToken but it did not work. Perhaps there is a different way to set up the artifact?

Here is my gradle.build file:

```
    credentials { 
        username "Testuser" 
        DevOps Services_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") : vstsMavenAccessToken 
        //password "<using raw token works>"
        //password System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
        password System.getenv("TOKEN")
    }
```

Here is my azure-pipelines.yml where I define the variables I use in the build.gradle file. token is a environment variable that I have set to the my actual token (which works). If I swap it and use the System.AccessToken it does not work:

```
steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'build'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    TOKEN: $(token)
```

Stay well and thanks for any help or insight!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to log into Azure DevOps Artifact feed without token

Just as what you tried, using `$(System.AccessToken)` should work fine. Just share my steps and some key points which you should pay attention to.

**Configuration**:

Here is part of my `build.gradle` file, and I applied the `$(System.AccessToken)` to publish package to my feed:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.microsoft.core'
            artifactId 'mock='
            version "${version}"
            artifact "build/libs/mock-${version}.jar"
        }
    }
    // Repositories *to* which Gradle can publish artifacts
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_packaging/{project name}/{feed name}/v1'
            credentials {
               username "Azure DevOps Services"  
               //password System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") : vstsMavenAccessToken
               password System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part of `YAML` definition:

```
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: Gradle Publish
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    tasks: 'publish'
  condition: always()
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

You can see my publish log and it published successfully:

[image]

---

Except the above script configuration, you also make configuration on your feed setting. Because the pipeline actual using Collection/project service account to access and perform actions in feed.

Please go feed setting, search and add `Project Collection Build Service ({org name})` and `{Porject name} Build Service ({org name})` into this permission setting. And assign them **Owner** role.

Now, re-build your pipeline and you will see it could succeed to access feed.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Adding "{Project name} Build Service ({org name})" solved the issue.

Comment: @ErnieAndBert It's welcome:-) glad it's just a permission issue. You can [accept this answer] and other SO members could directory know this is a worked solution

Comment: Spent 8 hours totally unnecessarily because I didn't read this answer correctly. I missed that "Project Collection" should be entered in verbatim, and all other answers (on other questions, and in documentation) only assumes that you're using project scoped pipelines so they only deals with "{Project name} Build Service ({org name})". Hoping that by pointing this out I'll save someone else the headache.